# How to order item is displayed on the page of the Checkout / Onepage / Success

Tags: magento

Magento Checkout process, the payment of page generally have this information:

===========================================

Your the order has been received.
Thank you for your purchase!

Your the order # is: 100 000 018.

You will receive an order confirmation email with details of your order and a link to track its progress.

Click here to the print a copy of your the order confirmation.

===========================================

If you want to increase the order item information, such as:

===========================================

The Items the Ordered
Product Name   SKU   Price   Qty   Subtotal's
ProductXXX     XXX   NT $ 543 1    NT $ 543

Subtotal's NT, $ 543
Shipping & Handling NT $ 5
The Grand the Total NT $ 548

===========================================

May I ask how to use the module to be completed?

I currently known, there are three major difficulties

1. Checkout to pay the shopping cart is empty
2. Checkout and Order screen (sales_order_view) is a different category
3. Success_checkout_Onepage, layout phtml is specified via XML, and may not be able to change the override to

I hope you can help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is create own module where rewrite standart action of Magento.
First of all rewrite success.phtml file (into your frontend layout file):

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
  <reference name="content">
    <reference name="checkout.success">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>your_module/success.phtml</template></action>
    <reference>
  </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

Rewrite Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success (into config.xml file of your module):

```
<global>
  <blocks>
    <checkout>
      <rewrite>
        <onepage_success>Your_module_name_Block_Success</links>
      </rewrite>
    </checkout>
  ...
```

Then we have to create this block (into our module) that should be exdends from Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success, example:

```
class Your_module_name_Block_Success extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success
{
  // Write here only your methods example get last order's products
  // All parent's methods also will work
}
```

Then you will describe method for getting products from order and execute it into your phtml file (see above). 
Tip: copy html from original file (all will be working) and then customize it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help someone else, as I'm replying quite late.

Bought product order grid is similar to "checkout cart", "checkout review" and "account my order". The grids can be displayed at checkout success page.

All necessay steps are given in [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/293713/).

Thanks,
Kashif